# Azure AD Configuration Azure App Service App Registration .NET 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to understand how to properly configure Azure AD Configuration when deploying to An Azure App Service as a proof of concept.

My specific use-case is Blazor Server, but the research I have conducted so far indicates it is a general ASPNET.Core question as far as I can tell.

I have created a standalone App Registration for local running/testing which is configured as follows:

User Secrets:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientCertificates": [
    ],
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
```

My configuration code in Program.cs is as follows:

```
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

When creating an Azure App Service an automatic App Registration is generated, but I'm struggling to understand how to utilise it in this context within my application.

I am using also KeyVault to retrieve an Azure Storage account connectionstring and during my tinkering to try and get things working noticed that one error I encountered when deploying was that it was trying to access my KeyVault using the Client ID of the App Registration associated with the creation of the Web App in the Azure portal. It also appears to create an associated client secret, but I am of course unable to see it in it's entirety as it is obfuscated.

Adding the necessary permissions to the KeyVault allowed the connection string to be retrieved.

I have managed to get things working so far using the existing standalone App Registration and having the "AzureAd" configuration stored in appsettings.json. The only exception is the ClientSecret that is  stored separately in the ConfigurationSettings of the App Service, but it just feels like it is not the correct way.

I think there is a missing piece in my understanding so any pointers would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You already had an Azure AD application and configured it in your blazor server app, which can run correctly in your local side right? Then you question

> configure Azure AD Configuration when deploying to An Azure App
> Service

only requires you to create an Azure web app instance, then in your VS, right click on your project -> publish -> Azure -> Azure APP Service -> enter your credential -> choose the resource group and find your web app created just now -> publish your app.

You don't have to create a new Azure AD application. And about your question

> KeyVault to retrieve an Azure Storage account connectionstring

If your code to retrieve Azure key vault secret looks like below:

```
var kvUri = "https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/";
var a = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), a);
var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
string secretVaule = secret.Value.Value;
```

Then you only need to add access policy in Azure Key vault and choose the Azure AD application as the principle. Then set environment variable in your local machine(when you test locally) and Azure web app settings with `AZURE_CLIENT_ID AZURE_TENANT_ID AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`. This is because of `DefaultAzureCredential`.
[image]

[image]

About the [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential), we can see screenshot below about the description. It will automatically choose a way to pass the credential and help us get the secret in key vault.

[image]

According to the document, if you don't want to set environment, you can also enable `Managed Identity` for your Azure web app, and add the azure web app as the principle in Azure key vault access policy.

[image]